# Having problems on my sign in form for firebase because of Error:"email" must be a valid string."

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

Good day developers , in this simple app im building , can't see the gap about my sign in form to firebase .Is weird that allows me to sign up creating a new user , but once this user is created , and i try to sign in with his security details got this error:Error in v-on handler: "Error: signInWithEmailAndPassword failed: First argument "email" must be a valid string.".

This app is based on Vue.Js having basic interaction with Firebase including this  signInWithEmailAndPassword function.
Here i'm referring part of my code that has to do with my issue

```
HTML tag for Log In Form

<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-container >
      <v-layout>
        <v-flex  class='d-flex justify-center'>
          <v-card   style="width:300px ;height:300px;margin-top:90px">
            <v-card-text>
              <v-container>
                <form @submit.prevent="signUserIn">
                  <v-layout row>
                    <v-flex xs12>
                      <v-text-field
                        name="name"
                        label="name"
                        id="name"
                        v-model="name"
                        type="name"
                        required
                      ></v-text-field>
                    </v-flex>
                  </v-layout>

                  <v-layout row>
                    <v-flex xs12>
                      <v-text-field
                        name="email"
                        label="email"
                        id="email"
                        v-model="email"
                        type="email"
                        required
                      ></v-text-field>
                    </v-flex>
                  </v-layout>

                  <v-layout row>
                    <v-flex xs12>
                      <v-text-field
                        name="password"
                        label="password"
                        id="password"
                        v-model="password"
                        type="password"
                        required
                      ></v-text-field>
                    </v-flex>
                  </v-layout>
                  <v-layout row>
                    <v-flex xs12>
                      <v-btn type="submit" class="primary">Sign In</v-btn>
                    </v-flex>
                  </v-layout>
                </form>
              </v-container>
            </v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

then v-modeling the fields of email, password and user, i set this on the data return

```
 data() {
    return {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      name: ""
    };
  },
```

Finally as last step of this first part simply commit the v-modeled information passed through this method  to my Management State in Vuex, which would be in charge to connect to Firebase:

```
Script Method

methods: {
    ...mapActions(["signUserIn"]),
    signingIn() {
      this.$store.dispatch("signUserIn", {
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password
      });
    }
  }
```

Then on my Managment State , the sign in function would be like this:

```
ACTION

signUserIn({ commit }, userInfo) {
      firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(userInfo.email, userInfo.password)

        .then(
          user => {
            const newUser = {
              id: user.uid,

            }
            commit('clearSettingAuthUserError')
            commit('settingSignedInUser', newUser)
          }
        )
        .catch(
          error => {
            commit('settingAuthUserError', error)
            console.log(error)
          }
        )
    },
MUTATION

 settingSignedInUser(state, payload) {
      state.user = payload
    },
GETTER
getUser(state) {
      return state.user
    },
```

Honestly can't perceive where the error is both in my HTML or my Vuex, being all more confusing cause it allows me to sign up , not letting me once created, to sign in with the same user.
Could somebody give me a clue about what im doing wrong ?.
Thanks , and have a good day!!!

Comment: What happens if you try to debug by looking at the value of email at each step? In the `signingIn()` method and in the action?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry was my own mistake!!!...should really review my code over and over before doing stupid questions guys.Really sorry....!!!
On the method linked to my form action i just call the action of my managment state

```
<form @submit.prevent="signUserIn">WRONG
```

instead of having called the method in my component which is the one in charge to then call the action from Vuex

```
<form @submit.prevent=" signingIn">CORRECT
```

Thanks to Renaud Tarnec for the time and interest on answer my question. And really sorry !!!